# A caesar cipher function that shift vowels "aeiou"

Tags: python, python-3.x, shift, caesar-cipher

So I am trying to write a function which shifts within the reference string of vowels "aeiou" and "AEIOU". Here is what I have so far:

```
vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"

    def encrypt(message, shift):
      output = ''
      for char in message:
        index = vowels.find(char)
        if index < 0: 
          output += ' '

        else:
          new_index = (index + shift) % len(vowels)
          new_character = vowels[new_index]
          output += new_character
      return output
```

What I want is, for example, if I enter encrypt("a",2), the output should be "i", encrypt("A",2) --> "I", however, if I enter encrypt("a",6), I want the output to be "e" not "E. And also when I enter something different than those vowels such as a number or "k", the function should return "k"or  the number. The last thing is what if I want to use the function I wrote to find all vowels in a string of sentence and shift them?

Comment: What if you gave `("O", 6)` what would be the expectation of the function ? raise an error or shift back round to the start and return `u`?

Comment: I want to shift back and return U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will make the shifts that you require, I believe.

```
vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"


def encrypt(message, shift):
    output = ''
    for char in message:
        index = vowels.find(char)
        if index < 0:
            output += char

        else:
            shift %= 5

            if index >= 5:
                new_index = (index + shift) % 5 + 5
            else:
                new_index = (index + shift) % 5
# Or, alternatively to the above 4 lines:
#           new_index = (index + shift) % 5 + 5 * int(index >= 5)
            new_character = vowels[new_index]
            output += new_character
    return output
```

```
encrypt('the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs', 1)
Out[3]: 'thi qaock bruwn fux jampid uvir thi lezy dugs'
encrypt('the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs'.upper(), 1)
Out[4]: 'THI QAOCK BRUWN FUX JAMPID UVIR THI LEZY DUGS'
encrypt('the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs'.upper(), 13)
Out[5]: 'THU QIACK BREWN FEX JIMPUD EVUR THU LOZY DEGS'
```

You can simplify the 4 line if statement by embedding the check for it being upper case into the addition, using the quality that int(True) is 1 and int(False) is 0

```
new_index = (index + shift) % 5 + 5 * int(index >= 5)
```

Comment: hehe you used the same sentence as me.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `maketrans` and `translate` methods of string to make a translation table and then translate the string.

```py
def ceaser_shift_vowels(sentance: str, offset: int):
    offset = offset % 5
    upper_clear = "AEIOU"
    lower_clear = "aeiou"
    upper_cipher = upper_clear[offset:] + upper_clear[:offset]
    lower_cipher = lower_clear[offset:] + lower_clear[:offset]
    translator = sentance.maketrans(upper_clear + lower_clear, upper_cipher + lower_cipher)
    return sentance.translate(translator)

sentance = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
for i in range(10):
    print(ceaser_shift_vowels(sentance, i))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
Thi qaock bruwn fux jamps uvir thi lezy dug
Tho qeuck brawn fax jemps avor tho lizy dag
Thu qiack brewn fex jimps evur thu lozy deg
Tha qoeck briwn fix jomps ivar tha luzy dig
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
Thi qaock bruwn fux jamps uvir thi lezy dug
Tho qeuck brawn fax jemps avor tho lizy dag
Thu qiack brewn fex jimps evur thu lozy deg
Tha qoeck briwn fix jomps ivar tha luzy dig
```

This also has the bennefit that to decrypt the string you just need to pass the offset as a negative

```py
sentance = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
offset = 6
crypt_string = ceaser_shift_vowels(sentance, offset)
print(crypt_string)
decrypt_string = ceaser_shift_vowels(crypt_string, -offset)
print(decrypt_string)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Thi qaock bruwn fux jamps uvir thi lezy dug
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Comment: Aren't lower case letters intended to remain lower case?

Comment: Umm... `ceaser_shift_vowels('a', 6)` returns `E` - the OP does say: *if I enter encrypt("a",6), I want the output to be "e" not "E*

Comment: oh were they? i thought they were to loop all the way around :(

Comment: ah doh didnt notice that

Comment: Updated to handle upper and lower case seperatly

Comment: @ChrisDoyle you don't really need two maketrans and translates here, you can create one translation table and use that, eg: `str.maketrans(upper_clear + lower_clear, upper_cipher + lower_cipher)`

Comment: Ah never even thought of that @JonClements, thanks. This is why i enjoy stack over flow cause always learn something new. updated answer based on your comment